# Error propagation for products

Tags: error-analysis

Suppose you have two measured (independent) physical quantities $x$ and $y$ with relative errors $r_x := \frac{\delta x}{x}$ and $r_y := \frac{\delta y}{y}$, where $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ are the corresponding absolute errors. Now you want to calculate $z = xy$ (or $z = \frac{x}{y}$).

Usually the relative error $r_z$ is calculated as

$$
r_z = \sqrt{r_x^2 + r_y^2}
$$

Sometimes (usually in lower level or high school courses) it is said that you have to take just the sum of the relative errors, i.e.

$$
r_z = r_x + r_y
$$

For example for the product this seems easy to derive: 
$$
\begin{align}
(x + \delta x)\cdot (y + \delta y) = xy + x \delta y + y \delta x + \delta x \delta y \\
(x - \delta x)\cdot (y - \delta y) = xy - x \delta y - y \delta x + \delta x \delta y \\
\end{align}
$$

Subtracting both equations you get for the right side: $2(x\delta y + y \delta x)$ and half of it seems to be a good measure for the absolute value of $\delta z$. So you get for the relative error $r_z$

$$
r_z = \frac{\delta z}{z} = \frac{x\delta y + y \delta}{xy} = \frac{\delta y}{y} + \frac{\delta x}{x} = r_y + r_x
$$

What's wrong with this reasoning?

What is the correct formula and why? Are there different domains of application of both formulas?

Comment: It wouldn't be unheard of to assume the product of the errors $\delta x \delta y$ is negligible, but this assumes that both are small numbers relative to x and y

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: You're right (and I closed the other one myself as dupe of that), I chose the dupe link too quickly.

Comment: "What's wrong with this reasoning?" Intuitively, what's wrong is that it assumes the errors all have the same sign, whereas in most cases you need to assume that the errors are *uncorrelated*. Sum ten uncorrelated noise terms together: what's the probability that they're all in the same direction? Its $2^{-9}\approx 0.002$. Even with two terms, the probability that they are both of the same sign is only a half. Half of the time, they will mitigate one another.